# can't include plot fully in graph for matlab gui, shows half of plot only

Tags: matlab, plot

This is a projectile motion graph, I have included the full calculations until the plotting of the graph. I don't understand how to change the settings of the graph using the code after the calculations part.
[this is what i've plotted using this code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3ON8.jpg)

```
time = linspace(0, t, 1000);
legends = {}; % Instantiate an empty cell for the angle legend.
counter = 1;
for A = 10: 10 : 90
% Get the components of velocity in the x and y directions for this angle.
vx = v*cosd(A);
vy = v*sind(A);
% Compute the distance along the x direction.  x = x0 + x_velocity * time.
xfinal = vx * time;
% Compute the distance along the y direction.  y = y0 + y_velocity_initial * 
%time + (1/2)*g*time^2
yfinal = vy * time + (1/2) * 9.81 * time .^ 2;
% Clip y to zero because we assume the projectile stays on the ground when 
%it hits.  
% It does not penetrate and have a negative y.
yfinal(yfinal < 0) = 0;
indexHitGround = find(yfinal > 0, 1, 'last');
fontSize=10
plot(xfinal, yfinal, '-', 'LineWidth', 2);
hold on;
legends{end+1} = sprintf('Angle = %d', A);
% Calculate the range in the x direction.
xFinal(counter) = xfinal(indexHitGround);
counter = counter + 1;
end
grid on;
xlabel('X Coordinate', 'FontSize', fontSize);
ylabel('Y Coordinate', 'FontSize', fontSize);
title ('Projectile Trajectory', 'FontSize', fontSize)
legend(legends);
% Find the max xFinal and set the range of the graph to be that.
xlim([0, max(xFinal)]);
% Set up figure properties:
% Enlarge figure to full screen.
set(gcf, 'Units', 'Normalized', 'OuterPosition', [0.2, 0.3, 0.8, 0.7]);
% Get rid of tool bar and pulldown menus that are along top of figure.
set(gcf, 'Toolbar', 'none', 'Menu', 'none');
% Give a name to the title bar.
set(gcf, 'Name', 'Projectile Trajectory Demo Part 2', 'NumberTitle', 'Off')
```

whereas I'm trying to plot something like this
[projectile trajectory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8abh.png)

I'm a newbie to matlab so I would really appreciate if you would point out the errors in my code or give me a few suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in the way you plot the data but in the equation used to compute the trajectory.

You have to change the sign of the acceleration component to `minus`.

Change

```
yfinal = vy * time + (1/2) * 9.81 * time .^ 2;
```

to

```
yfinal = vy * time - (1/2) * 9.81 * time .^ 2;
```

In your code, `t` and `v` are not defined, I've used some values to test the code.

Also with respect to the picture of the desired graph, the `y0` is not defined (and not used in the equation), perhaps you might change the equation to

```
yfinal = y0+ vy * time - (1/2) * 9.81 * time .^ 2;
```

setting `y0=10` the trajectories look like:

[image]